# Javac on a JUnit Class Also Compiles The Source Class

Tags: java, junit, javac

Ok.  am running the following command to compile my TestClass

```
javac -cp .:$PROJECT_DIR/src/:$PROJECT_DIR/tools/* -d $PROJECT_DIR/output/test/ $PROJECT_DIR/test/com/proj1/ome/testClassA
```

It compiles testClassA.  However it also compiles classA.  So in my output/test/ directory I have both classA.class and testClassA.class.

I don't want the compiled classA to be in this directory.  So I am looking for either a way to compile testClassA without compiling classA or a flag to change the directory of classA.  I have dug through the javac documentation and haven't found anything, though.

Any ideas or help would be great.

Comment: @DaveNewton That worked great.  I didn't realize it was out of necessity, just thought it always did it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the compiled `classA` on the classpath, which apparently isn't the `src` directory (nor should it be, IMO). This way `javac` won't have to automatically compile `classA` and put it in the output directory you specify when you compile the test class.